# Getting an error while executing query on MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, file-io, load

Hello I am getting the following error when doing the following query, I am executing both queries at the same time:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Some_Data (Event_index INT, Record_index INT, Device_index SMALLINT, Phone_ID SMALLINT, Transaction_ID SMALLINT, Probe_Seq_Count SMALLINT, Probe_Seq_Result TEXT(100), Duration_Slots INT, Probe_PN SMALLINT, Probe_Sector INT, Probe_Color_Code SMALLINT, Sum_Probe_Count INT) ENGINE = INNODB; 
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/path/data.csv' INTO TABLE Some_Data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';"
```

> ERROR: Query upload Error: (2014, "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now")

This is the code I am using, please help:

```
# Connecto to the MySQL server
    self.Connect()

    if(_VERBOSITY):
        print('\tUpload start')

    # Upload the data
    for table in tableDDL:
        try:
            self.cursor.execute(tableDDL[table])
            #self.conn.commit()
            #results = self.cursor.fetchall()
            #print(results)
            break

        except MySQLdb.Error as err:
            print('\tERROR: Query upload Error: %s' % err)
            print('\t%s' % tableDDL[table])
            sys.exit(1)
        except Exception as err:
            print('Error: %s' % err.message)
            sys.exit(1)
        except:
            print('\tERROR: some other error: %s' % (sys.exc_info()[0]))
            sys.exit(1)
```

The user under the following privileges:

```
GRANT CREATE, DROP, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE, LOCK TABLES ON access.* TO 'some_user'@'localhost';
GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'some_user'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the SQL statement when the error is generated (i.e. the  value of tableDDL[table])?

Comment: The string query has both statements, one after the other: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Some_Data (Event_index INT, Record_index INT, Device_index SMALLINT, Phone_ID SMALLINT, Transaction_ID SMALLINT, Probe_Seq_Count SMALLINT, Probe_Seq_Result TEXT(100), Duration_Slots INT, Probe_PN SMALLINT, Probe_Sector INT, Probe_Color_Code SMALLINT, Sum_Probe_Count INT) ENGINE = INNODB;\nLOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/path/data.csv' INTO TABLE Some_Data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n';"

Comment: Have you tried running each command separately to ensure each works on its own.  If not, which fails?

Comment: The following query works manually but it does not work via the cursor, and no error is generated when executing the command via the cursor: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/someuser/data.csv' INTO TABLE Some_Data FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

Comment: It seems very unlikely that `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` will work like this.  When run in the MySQL CLI, some additional unseen magic occurs that transfers the contents of the `LOCAL` file to the server.